# How to Parallel Prim’s Algorithm using MPI in C?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

The code in sequencial

**Now i need to parellel using MPI (Message Passing Interface)**

```
 // A C / C++ program for Prim's Minimum Spanning Tree (MST) algorithm.
// The program is for adjacency matrix representation of the graph

#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>


// Number of vertices in the graph
#define V 5

// A utility function to find the vertex with minimum key value, from
// the set of vertices not yet included in MST
int minKey(int key[], bool mstSet[])
{
   // Initialize min value
   int min = INT_MAX, min_index;

   for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
     if (mstSet[v] == false && key[v] < min)
         min = key[v], min_index = v;

   return min_index;
}

// A utility function to print the constructed MST stored in parent[]
int printMST(int parent[], int n, int graph[V][V])
{
   printf("Edge   Weight\n");

   for (int i = 1; i < V; i++)
      printf("Threads %d - %d - %d    %d \n", parent[i], i, graph[i][parent[i]]);
}

// Function to construct and print MST for a graph represented using adjacency
// matrix representation
void primMST(int graph[V][V])
{
     int parent[V]; // Array to store constructed MST
     int key[V];   // Key values used to pick minimum weight edge in cut
     bool mstSet[V];  // To represent set of vertices not yet included in MST

     // Initialize all keys as INFINITE

     for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        key[i] = INT_MAX, mstSet[i] = false;

     // Always include first 1st vertex in MST.
     key[0] = 0;     // Make key 0 so that this vertex is picked as first vertex
     parent[0] = -1; // First node is always root of MST

     // The MST will have V vertices

     for (int count = 0; count < V-1; count++)
     {
        // Pick thd minimum key vertex from the set of vertices
        // not yet included in MST
        int u = minKey(key, mstSet);

        // Add the picked vertex to the MST Set
        mstSet[u] = true;

        // Update key value and parent index of the adjacent vertices of
        // the picked vertex. Consider only those vertices which are not yet
        // included in MST

        for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)

           // graph[u][v] is non zero only for adjacent vertices of m
           // mstSet[v] is false for vertices not yet included in MST
           // Update the key only if graph[u][v] is smaller than key[v]
          if (graph[u][v] && mstSet[v] == false && graph[u][v] <  key[v])
             parent[v]  = u, key[v] = graph[u][v];
     }

     // print the constructed MST
     printMST(parent, V, graph);
}


// driver program to test above function
int main()
{
   /* Let us create the following graph
          2    3
      (0)--(1)--(2)
       |   / \   |
      6| 8/   \5 |7
       | /     \ |
      (3)-------(4)
            9          */
   int graph[V][V] = {{0, 2, 0, 6, 0},
                      {2, 0, 3, 8, 5},
                      {0, 3, 0, 0, 7},
                      {6, 8, 0, 0, 9},
                      {0, 5, 7, 9, 0},
                     };

    // Print the solution
    primMST(graph);

    return 0;
}
```

Message Passing Interface (MPI) is a standardized and portable message-passing system designed by a group of researchers from academia and industry to function on a wide variety of parallel computers. The standard defines the syntax and semantics of a core of library routines useful to a wide range of users writing portable message-passing programs in C, C++, and Fortran. There are several well-tested and efficient implementations of MPI, many of which are open-source or in the public domain. These fostered the development of a parallel software industry, and encouraged development of portable and scalable large-scale parallel applications.

Comment: That last paragraph looks as if it should carry attribution.

Comment: .... and is completely superfluous to the question. Smells like copied from an assignment which was in turn copied from Wikipedia. Obviously the same for the code.